# How can we find the signal power of \$x_{out}(t)=\frac{1}{2}Am(t)cos \theta\$?

Tags: power, signal, communication

I am trying to solve the following question:

[image]

I have partially worked out the problem and we have:

\$x_{out}(t)=\frac{1}{2}Am(t)cos \theta\$, which is the output of the LPF.

and

\$x(t)=Am(t)cos (2\pi f_c t)\$

My problem is that how can I find out the power of \$x_{out}(t)\$ and \$x(t)\$ because I don't know the amplitude of \$m(t)\$. Moreover, if \$m(t)\$ is not a singletone frequency signal, how can we find out the power of \$x_{out}(t)\$ and \$x(t)\$ ?

> ***In short my question is:***
>
> How can we find the power of
>
> \$x_{out}(t)=\frac{1}{2}Am(t)cos \theta\$
>
> and
>
> \$x(t)=Am(t)cos (2\pi f_c t)\$?

Answer (score 2):

$$x_{out}(t)=\frac{1}{2}Am(t)cos \theta$$
I can group constants together and write this as:
$$x_{out}(t)=(\frac{1}{2}Acos \theta V_m)cos\omega_m t$$
By the general definition of power of a sinusoidal wave,
$$P_1 = \frac{(\frac{1}{2}Acos \theta V_m)^2}{2}$$
$$=\frac{1}{8}A^2V_m^2cos^2\theta$$
Now \$x(t)=Am(t)cos (\omega_c t)\$,
$$\implies x(t) = AV_mcos(\omega_mt)cos(\omega_ct) ----(1)$$

I can write x(t) as sum of two sinusoids:
$$\implies x(t) = \frac{AV_m}{2}(cos(\omega_c+\omega_m)t+cos(\omega_c-\omega_m)t)$$
$$\implies x(t) = \frac{AV_m}{2}cos(\omega_c+\omega_m)t+\frac{AV_m}{2}cos(\omega_c-\omega_m)t$$

These represents two side bands of the DSB-SC modulated wave. Sum of the sideband powers will be the total power of the modulated wave.

$$\implies P_2 = \frac{A^2V_m^2}{8} + \frac{A^2V_m^2}{8} = \frac{1}{4}A^2V_m^2 $$

$$\therefore P_1/P_2 = \frac{1}{2} cos^2\theta$$

Comment: Thanks for helping me. But in case $m(t)$ is not a single toned frequency signal, but any arbitrary signal, can we find out the ratio $P_1/P_2$ by considering the power of $m(t)$ as $P$.(and then taking the ratio and cancelling $P$...). If you work out this please retain the calculation you have done above. Thank you :)

Comment: You have done a little mistake while typing. $P_1/P_2 = \frac{1}{2} cos^2 \theta$

Comment: No. In general for signals, you cant simply do that. You have to find the power using the conventional expression for power of a periodic signal using integration. Here notice that I have just added the powers of two side bands to compute the total power of the sum of those two signals. In general we cannot do it. Cz Power doesnt have linearity relation. You can use integration method to find power of x(t) and you will notice that one intermediate term occurs. But here in DSB-SC scheme, bandpass filter has removed that intermediate term. Thats why power is simply sum of the sidebands.

Comment: Please always mark an answer as accepted if it solves your problem.